# How to add new line in Open office spreadsheet Cell?

Tags: openoffice.org

I am working on an OpenOffice spreadsheet which needs some listing of content. e.g: Modules:

1. Add user
2. Add customer

I can't format the text in the cell. Please assist me if anyone has done the new line in the spreadsheet cell.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enter a newline in a cell, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: newline in cell]

Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_Line_Breaks_in_Cells

Comment: Which version of OpenOffice  you are using?
Mine is 4.1.2 , ctrl+entr is not working.

Comment: Did you place the text edit cursor inside the cell, according to the instructions in the documentation?  IIRC, it's worked on every version and every OS I've ever tried, going back to OOo 1.1.  It worked again just now with AOO 4.1.3 on Windows.   The only other possibility I can think of is that the keyboard hotkeys have been changed from the default settings.  In that case, it may help to [reset the profile](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile).  Or, perhaps your operating system is configured to intercept that key combination.

Comment: I am using 4.1.7 on Ubuntu and Jim's solution is working. As he said it is important, that the cursor is in the cell. You can achieve this by clicking twice on the cell. Then you can use the mentioned command.

Comment: If left ctrl + enter is not working, try right ctrl + enter